# Android Java - IOException when flush() to server

Tags: java, android, outputstream, ioexception

I'm trying to post data to my server. If I am posting just once, everything runs properly. But when I try to do a `for loop` (or have the loop run more than once) then only the first loop gets posted and after that I get an `IOExecption`.

```
try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

                JSONObject objLog = new JSONObject();
                objLog.put("a", "a");
                objLog.put("b", "b");

                String datalog = objLog.toString();
                ow.write(datalog);     
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //close 
        }
```

This is the error I get:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: closed

Comment: Why don’t you use an out of the box library like Volley, https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you create a lot of readers and writers.

Wrong.

Create only one of each before the loops.

But i wonder why you have the first loop.

Looks wrong too.

Better remove.